# Почему не работает функция?

Tags: javascript, функции

```
<html>
<head>
<title>massiv</title>
</head>
<body>

<script >
var m=new Array(6,9,10);
m[0]=8;
m[2]='Hello';
function f()
 {
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
 window.alert(m[i]);

}
</script>
<form name="myform"> 
<input type=button value="Вывести массив" onclick f()>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `onclick f()` — это, надеюсь, опечатка?

Comment: точно опечатка

Comment: и что тогда нужно было вам ответить? 

Comment: Вы опечатались 3 раза в этом маленьком коде! Для начала, проверяйте код на синтаксические ошибки, запускайте консоль, и смотрите результат.. а потом сюда уже пишите..

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>massiv</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var m = new Array(6, 9, 10);
    m[0] = 8;
    m[2] = 'Hello';

    function f() {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //Опечатка 1
          window.alert(m[i]);
        }
      } //Опечатка 2
  </script>

  <form name="myform">
    <input type=button value="Вывести массив" onclick="f()" comment="<--Опечатка 3">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Отпечатка))

Comment: 3 отпечатки! Это много!

p.s. после моих исправлений заработало?

Comment: хм, неужели в js нельзя выбросить фигурные скобки, если блок состоит из одного оператора? в C, C++, Java, C#, Pascal можно.

Comment: может и можно, но зачем?

Я ни в java ни в js (больше языков не знаю) никогда не выбрасываю. Код как-то чище смотрится ;)

p.s. Разве в паскале фигурки? Там же вроде begin end?